# npm install: Use global package if it exists, rather than installing twice

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When using `npm install` with a `package.json` file, how do I get it to use a globally installed package that meets the criteria instead of downloading and installing the package locally again?

I know about [`link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link), but is there a way to do what I'm describing?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the motivation behind this?

Comment: @PatrickMotard Deduplication

Comment: There are many motivations, but the big one is to save on disk space. Developers may have 10 different installations of the same version of Express, Gulp, Istanbul, NYC or Babel, and it's just...a waste of space on disk. And developer time, copying files from one location to another on disk.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible, but I'd be interested to find out if it is!

Answer (score 2):

Yarn seems to work much better with repeated dependencies. So try `yarn install` instead of `npm install`.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it for a specific set of modules is removing these modules from the `dependencies` section and creating a `prestart` script that contains all the modules that you prefer having installed globally.

A simple example might look something like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "prestart": "npm i -g mocha mysql bluebird"
  },
```

Instead of `prestart` you can use one of the other hooks such as `preinstall` and `prepare`.
Note that this won't work as-is with packages you want to publish and would require a bit more hacking.

Help on running scriipts: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts