# handling duplicate npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I have submodules that install the same npm packages. Their node modules install same npm packages as other node modules in the repo. How can i consolidate all of the npm packages into one package.json file so that there are no duplicate packages installed?

Comment: This is not recommended since the submodules you use may require a different version of the "same" package. The reason node.js works this way is to avoid dependency hell (used to be called dll hell)

Comment: Or npm could just put all versions of all packages in one folder on the filesystem, and be done with it. Anybody know why NPM chose not to do this? Locks? Security? Just to be different?

Answer (score 1):

Had a nasty bug with NPM duplicating nested modules. Switching to Yarn helped.
So try `yarn install` instead of `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

@slebetman is correct. Libraries may share dependencies, but they will likely use different versions of each. Also, shameless plug to a [*very* similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370396/npm-install-use-global-package-if-it-exists-rather-than-installing-twice) I answered a while back where someone was essentially asking "Why not install dependencies globally so we don't have to reinstall over and over what we already have?"

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37370523/3199310).